# Python - Try and Except not working

Tags: python

I am making a game for a computer science assessment, simple counter game. Using Try and Excpet clause to only allow the user to input 1 or 2 for counter choice. But only repeats the 'Try' section and does not go to 'Except'.

Here is the code:

```
while True:
    try:
        selected_piece = int(input("Which piece would you like to move? (1/2):  "))
        if selected_piece == 1 or selected_piece == 2:
            break
    except:
        print("Please enter either (1/2):  ")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
while True:
        selected_piece = int(input("Which piece would you like to move? (1/2):  "))
        if selected_piece not in [1,2]:
            print("Invalid input, please try again.")
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Crashes with non-numeric input though.

Answer (score 2):

You only enter the except block if you raise an exception. So something like

```
while True:
    try:
        selected_piece = int(input("Which piece would you like to move? (1/2):  "))
        if selected_piece == 1 or selected_piece == 2:
            raise Exception("Invalid number selected")
    except:
        print("Please enter either (1/2):  ")
```

Note that it isn't recommended that you use exceptions to control the flow of your program. You will want to do what [Padraic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23859680/276949) suggests instead.

Answer (score 0):

Id always try to avoid using break or continue they can be a bit dodgy. You could try putting it into a function and calling it when you need to use it:

```
def getInput():
    validInput = False
    while not validInput:
        usrInput = input("Which piece would you like to move? (1/2):  ")
        if usrInput in ['1','2']:
            validInput = True
            return int(usrInput)
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please try again.")
```